# How to convert 18 bits two-complements into float number using java

Tags: java, twos-complement

The data is uploaded by 18-bits ADC. One data is split into three bytes and the last 6 bits is useless. The reference voltage is 1 volt, that means 0x1FFFF represents 1 and 0x3FFFF represents -1. How to convert 18-bits twos-complement into float using java. I have written one and it works, but I think it is not efficient enough. My java is terrible.

```
    float data;
    int value = ((byte0 & 0xff) << 10) | ((byte1 & 0xff) << 2) | ((byte2 & 0xff) >> 6); // combine 3 bytes into int  
    int tmp = value & 0x2000;   // judge positive or negative

    if (tmp != 0) {
        value = value - 262144 /* 2^18 */;
        data = ((float)value) * 2 / 262143 /* 2^18-1 */;
    } else {
        data = ((float)value) * 2 / 262143;
    }
```

Comment: Except I’d declare 262144 and 262143 names constants initialized from hex (or octal) literals I think your code is fine.

Comment: how often is this code running? did you evaluate which percent of processor time it consumes? It well may turn out to be a negligible fraction.

Comment: are you sure the code works? looks like it returns positive float for negative input.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code. When the input is negative, it should minus 2^18 first. I have corrected the code.

Comment: 0x2000 is not the 18th bit, it should be 0x20000

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
double data = (value << 14) / (double) (0x1FFFF << 14);
```

This will use a shifted 32-bit 2s complement value.

NOTE: If it was 2s complement, 0x3ffff should be the smallest negative number, and 0x20000 is the largest negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sign bit of the ADC in the same place as the sign bit of a 32-bit integer and you can simplify by using the native sign.

```
public static final float ADC_RANGE = 1.0f; // From -1V to +1V
public static final int   ADC_BITS  = 18;
public static final int   ADC_RANGE = 1 << (ADC_BITS - 1);
public static final int   ADC_MASK  = (ADC_RANGE - 1) << (32 - ADC_BITS);

    int bits = ((byte0 & 0xFF) << 24) | ((byte1 & 0xFF) << 16) | ((byte2 & 0xC0) << 8); // Combine 3 bytes into int, left-aligned
    float value = bits / (float)ADC_MASK * ADC_RANGE;
```

[edit] use constants for 'magic numbers'

Comment: I tested the code. It works but the result needs to divide (2^18-1). A problem is that if I want to use just one divisor (e.g. value = bits / divisor), the divisor is too big to represent by a constant. The division operation must be used twice or more.

Comment: You said you had 18 bits of which one is the sign bit, so to get a range of -1..+1 you divide by 2^17-1. `ADC_MASK` is 2^17-1, just left-aligned in an int.  What do you mean with too big to represent by a constant?

Comment: Sorry, I understood wrong. I tried to run your code but it can not compile successfully because there is a float ADC_RANGE and an int ADC_RANGE.